# How was Ali's reception of the attack on Fatima by Umar (and Abu Bakr)

Tags: shiism

**Background**

According to Shia historians, one of the earliest conflicts between some of the Companions and Ahl al-Bayt is the attack on Fatima's house by Umar in order to arrest/subdue Ali, who refused to give his Bay'ah to Abu Bakr.

According to Sulaym ibn Qays, Umar set the door on fire, pushing his way into the house. Upon Fatima's resistance, Umar physically assaulted her using a sheathed sword. While this narration mentions a fight between Ali and Umar, others (Ibn Abi'l-Hadid for example) claim that Ali was busy at the Funeral of the Prophet and did not witness the incident. ibn Qays later mentions that Fatima still carried the bruises from this raid when she died soon after.

Some Shia also believe that Muhsin ibn Ali, the youngest son of Ali, brother of Husayn, was killed in miscarriage due to Umar's attack.

**How was Ali's reception?**

I fail to find later any response from Ali later on this attack; moreover, Islamic historians (both Shia and Sunnah) show later collaboration between both Ali and Umar. Although Shia books mention some clashes, none of them are related to the incident.

I personally interpret this incident (if we were to believe the narration's authenticity) to be a great insult to Ahl al-Bayt. My question is: Was there any reverberation from Ali or the early Shia of Ali on this incident? If the answer is no, why?

Comment: Imam Ali a.s. said the Roman empire and the Persian empire both were seeking an opportunity to eliminate Islam totally as an escalating danger. so if he started a civil war the Muslim society power became weak and those powers could kill all Muslims and Islam totally finished on earth because Islam was still small and young. so he preferred to not start a civil war against those 3. so he preferred survival of Islam against his own position as a Caliph.